# Use nbtstat to return list of host names in IP range?

Tags: script, cmd.exe, hostname, command-line-arguments, windows-networking

In Windows 7 I'm using the command `for /l %i in (1,1,254) do nbtstat -a xxx.xxx.xxx.%i` to return host names based on a given IP range.  But the output is so long and unfriendly.  How could I improve it to return a list that looks more like a spreadsheet like:

`IP address     Host name     MAC address
xxx.xxx.xxx.1  host-name-01  xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-x1
xxx.xxx.xxx.2  host-name-02  xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-x2
xxx.xxx.xxx.3  host-name-03  xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-x3`
?

I've seen commands that have something like  `| list xxx` at the end, but I'm not super-familiar with that particular syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to change "UNIQUE" to the local equivalent in the output.

```
@echo off
set PREFIX=127.0.0
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /l %%i in (1,1,254) do ( 
nbtstat -a %PREFIX%.%%i > %TEMP%\info.txt 
for /F "tokens=4" %%a in ('findstr "MAC" %TEMP%\info.txt') do set MAC=%%a
for /F "tokens=1" %%a in ('findstr /R /C:"<00>  UNIQUE " %TEMP%\info.txt' ) do set HOSTNAME=%%a
echo %PREFIX%.%%i;%MAC%;%HOSTNAME%
)
```